# NavigationContainer Blank - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

The NavigationContainer in React Native is showing blank data. When I remove it, I can see data. I tried recreating the scenario using the example from the documentation, and I got the same issue. It might have something to do with the downloads, but I'm pretty sure I downloaded everything.

Using this exact code from the documentation, i get a blank screen on my simulator:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```